# Create a Typo3 distribution without fileadmin

Tags: typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

We are creating a TYPO3 distribution for templating, here our client wants to handle the page content images in seperate/another folder instead of fileadmin. Is any way there to achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

Since TYPO3 6 you can create additional file storages. These could replace or add to the default file storage (`/fileadmin/`). You even might just change the default file storage to another path.

The records for file storages are stored in the root-page (uid = 0). Go there and edit/create them.

Don't forget to give your editors access to these storages.
And enable the matching rights to those folders.